# Exception in Tkinter callback; KeyError: 'Id'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on my Tkinter And Opencv Based face recog based attendance system. 
PS- NEW NOOB CODER HERE..
Everything works fine until the point when i click to track images button so that face can be recognised and attendance can be taken automatically and save it but as soon as it turns on the camera and frame, it gets stuck with the Console Showing the Error

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Id'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\relan\Desktop\Aman\New folder\Face-Recognition-Based-Attendance-System-master\train.py", line 195, in TrackImages
    aa=df.loc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Id'
```

The Frame gets stuck and i have to force quit the program..
My trackImage function code looks like

```
def TrackImages():

    col_names =  ['Id','Name','Date','Time']
    attendance = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)    
    while True:
        ret, im =cam.read()
        gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2,5)    
        for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(225,0,0),2)
            Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])                                   
            if(conf < 50):
                ts = time.time()      
                date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                aa=df.loc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
                tt=str(Id)+"-"+aa
                attendance.loc[len(attendance)] = [Id,aa,date,timeStamp]

            else:
                Id='Unknown'                
                tt=str(Id)  
            if(conf > 75):
                noOfFile=len(os.listdir("ImagesUnknown"))+1
                cv2.imwrite("ImagesUnknown\Image"+str(noOfFile)
```

Using Python 3.7.0.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We do not need all your code. Just a simple example that shows the problem area.

Comment: @Mike-SMT i am sorry about that but i cannot figure out where the error is..

Comment: instead of " if(conf < 50): " can you try " if 'Id' in df and (conf < 50): "

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no attemp to debug.

Comment: Retagged, since the exception is coming from the Pandas data frame, so none of the OpenCV and tkinter stuff is relevant. Please reduce this to [mcve], then we can continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `" if(conf < 50): "` ->`" if 'Id' in df and (conf < 50): "` Seems to work for me.